# Strange this.next() in onBeforeAction msg

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm geting a strange warning

"Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?"

I've seen this before and know how to work my way around it.

Except there's nothing wrong with my route and everything is working properly. The warning is just there and everything is seemingly working.

The route I have goes something like this:

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
    if ( mobile) {
        this.render('mobile')
    } else {
        if( !Meteor.userId()){
            this.render('not_logged_in')
        }
        this.next()
    }

},
action: function(){
    // Do action here
}
```

Again, using this route, the app is working fine.

But the warning appears. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `this.next()` for both of the conditional results, or once at the end to guarantee progression:

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
    if ( mobile) {
        this.render('mobile');
    } else {
        if( !Meteor.userId()){
            this.render('not_logged_in');
        }
    }
    this.next();
},
action: function(){
    // Do action here
}
```

Comment: What if I DON'T want to call next()??

I just want the route to stop there if mobile or not logged in.

Comment: @Mscope it's really best to leave that up to template logic. In my apps, I show a "notLoggedIn" template when the user is not logged.

Comment: @Mcope You will still need to call next() because it is required. Otherwise the route will fail completely, even worse the URL will change but the existing rendered template will remain (minus its data) so you'll confuse the user even more. An alternative is to Router.go('your.named.route') to a different route of your choosing, perhaps a login or denied 'page'.